# Why VS Code autocomplete doesn't suggest .value attribute when working with Java Script file?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

**HTML:**

```html
  <body>
    <h1>Grocery List</h1>
    <form action="/nowhere">
      <label for="item">Enter A Product</label>
      <input type="text" id="product" name="product" />
      <label for="item">Enter A Quantity</label>
      <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="list"></ul>
  </body>
```

**Java Script:**

```js
const frm = document.querySelector("form");
const prdct = document.querySelector("#product");
const qty = document.querySelector("#qty");
const mylst = document.querySelector("#list");

frm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const myele = document.createElement("li");
  myele.textContent = qty.value;
  myele.textContent += ` ${prdct.value}`;
  mylst.appendChild(myele);
  qty.value = "";
  prdct.value = "";
});
```

As can be seen, VS code isn't suggesting '.value' attribute with other suggestions. What can be the reason?

[image: VS code not suggesting .value attribute]

Comment: What is `prdct`?

Comment: First of all what type is a prdct? I'd assume the one you think it is conflicts with what VSCode thinks it is. My suggestion would be switching to typescript, there is no other way to tell your IDE to autocomplete things properly without providing a type for a thing

Comment: @JSEvgeny I've updated the code. 'prdct' is an object containing the form input.

Comment: welcome in the realm of loosely typed languages! There's no way for the editor to know the exact type of a javascript variable because it's known only at runtime (unless doing weak assumptions).

Comment: anyway the only elements having the value property (or html value attribute) are <button>, <data>, <input>, <li>, <meter>, <option>, <progress>, <param> as listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes. The editor cannot know that the variable holds a compatible html element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Document.querySelector()` returns a `Element`, so the editor cannot know that it has a `value`.

If you would create the element by javascript, then the editor DOES know...

```
let input = document.createElement("input")
let test = input.value // now you can get autocomplete
```

Another way is to use typescript :

```
let input:HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector("myinput")!
let test = input.value // now you can get autocomplete
```